# Hovering Button Issues

Tags: html, css

I have placed a button on my page and whenever I hover over that button, my text and

---

slightly shifts upwards. Please help (I am a beginner/novice/green) - the code will be shown below

```css
.btn {
  font-weight: 700px;
  border-radius: 500px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-color: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn-xl {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background-color: #4B307B;
  border-color: white;
}

.btn-xl:hover {
  background-color: gold;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #4B307B;
}

hr {
  border-color: gold;
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center h-100">
  <div class="row">
    <header class="text-center col-12">
      <h1 class="text-uppercase"><strong>Graduation Support</strong></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="buffer col-12"></div>
    **
    <section class="text-center col-12">
      <hr>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find out more</button>
    </section>**
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which button are you talking about?

Comment: Remove `border-width: 3px;` from  `.btn-xl:hover{..}`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `border-width: 3px;` to the `.btn-xl` class as well, not just the hover class.  I believe its the border appearing on the hover that is causing the issue.  See here:

```css
.btn{
    font-weight: 700px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.btn-xl{
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    background-color: #4B307B;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 3px;

}
.btn-xl:hover{
    background-color: gold;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #4B307B;

}

hr{
    border-color: gold;
    width: 150px;
    max-width: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="row">
                <header class="text-center col-12">
                <h1 class="text-uppercase"><strong>Graduation Support</strong></h1>
                </header>
                <div class="buffer col-12"></div>
            **<section class="text-center col-12">
                <hr>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find out more</button>
            </section>**
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I simply used OP's code to illustrate my fix specifically to the issue he had and it seemed to work for him.

Comment: @John your answer is correct, but it could be improved: 1. the CSS is incomplete (the last line), 2. there is an extra `:` in the last line (it is probably a typo), 3. The Bootstrap structure of OP is incorrect (too many `col-12`, misuse of `<section>` and `<header>` tags, can make use of more Bootstrap CSS helper classes, `border-radius` should use `rem` instead of `px` (as it's responsive),etc.)

Comment: Ok I fixed a few syntax errors.  Again I was not paying attention to this as it had nothing to do with the answer the OP was looking for. I simply Used his code with my change to fix the specific problem he had.